# Datastax Enterprise: Failed to open thrift connection to Cassandra at 172.31.XXX.XXX:9160

Tags: cassandra, apache-spark, cassandra-2.0, datastax, datastax-enterprise

Where can I change the port? I've tried changing in cassandra.yaml (rpc_address) but it still looks for this 172.xxx host. Reset server and still doesnt pick it up.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to change the port for Thrift there's an `rpc_port` setting in `cassandra.yaml`. (*Depending on what connector you are using, there might be other confs that need to be updated.*)